# ghc-mod: After update, `cannot satisfy -package-id base-4.8.2.0`

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-mod

So, an apt-get update in Ubuntu updated my GHC-version to 7.10.3 from [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc).

After this update, everything broke, so I switched to 7.10.2, from that same repository.

Almost everything is working now, except for ghc-mod, which when run, gives the following error when I try to check my project:

```
ghc-mod: <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id base-4.8.2.0-9bb65294401b6ef629a229811a1f4249
    (use -v for more information)
```

When I run cabal-install on my project, I don't get any dependency errors.

What might be causing this problem? Is there a setting within GHC-mod that needs to be changed, or a path that needs to be specified?

I can provide more information, but I just don't know where to start with this error.

My build-depends section in the .cabal file looks like this:

```
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9
                       , mtl
                       , parsec
                       , pretty
                       , readline
```

Like I said, these dependencies all install fine.

Comment: did you compile `ghc-mod` yourself ? what's the output of `ghc-mod --version`

Comment: did you find what was going wrong ? I think I have the same pb with 7.10.3

Comment: Seems to be an issue in 7.10.3: https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod/issues/607

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember exactly how I solved this... I think I just started a fresh sandbox and it worked?

Answer (score 1):

It seems restarting the ghc-mod process after a `rm -rf .stack-work` helps; `stack clean` doesn't seem "strong" enough for some reason — `ghc-mod` is not particularly clever about when it should clean and rebuild — wish that wasn't the case but it is.

---

Alternatively, your `ghc-mod` might need to be recompiled with whatever GHC version it's being used with; if you have multiple versions of GHC installed and need `ghc-mod` for a specific one, pass `-w path/to/ghc` to `cabal install`, for example in my case I have 8.0.1 globally but need `ghc-mod` with 7.10.3, which `stack` has already installed for me under `.stack/programs`:

```
~/my-sandboxes/ghc-mod-7.10.3 $ cabal install -w ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc ghc-mod
```

otherwise, a simple `cabal install ghc-mod` should do.

Comment: This is probably a solution, but I wasn't using stack when I originally encountered this.